# Heat Transfer From Resistance Element to Metal Component

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

I have a device that produces heat via Nichrome coils. I want to heat another small piece of metal (in this case stainless steel) with those Nichrome coils. I need to reach 175 degrees C, and so far I haven't found a readily available thermal adhesive that will work in my temperature range.

Is there a high temperature thermal adhesive available to consumers that I could use? Any suggestions on another way to effectively transfer the heat from the coils to my small metal component?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you give a sketch of what you'd like to accomplish and give more details on your intended application?

Comment: how about  insulate the assembly and rely on radiant heat transfer?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. To give a little more detail: I need to fuse two pieces of very thin filament (0.3mm diameter) with a melting temperature of ~175 C.  Due to the low volume of material to be melted, I think I can safely use a "relatively" small piece of metal to melt the filament.  I was hoping to use a high temp thermal adhesive to provide effective heat transfer from the nichrome coils that I'm using to the small metal piece.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [muffler cement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BOAZM8) from your local automotive shop. It would probably be good to keep the wire temp below 500C even though suppliers boast higher. Remember that if you want the metal to get to 175C in a reasonable amount of time, the wire temp will have to be higher than the 175C regardless of how well it is thermally connected.

Most existing products that I have repaired or torn down use a high temp ceramic resistor, fiberglass insulated resistor or fiberglass insulated resistance wire. The wire or resistor is then physically clamped against the surface to be heated. Higher end products will use [low cost thermal grease](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Z9XG0I) at the interface. [Silver filled thermal grease](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087X728K) is even better, but probably unnecessary.

[Fiberglass insulated resistance wire 750C](http://reachelectrical.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&category_id=209&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=866&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=177)
[Fiberglass insulated resistance wire 350C](http://www.reachelectrical.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&category_id=209&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=703&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=177)
[Chassis mount aluminum housed resistors rated 275C](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/resistors/chassis-mount-resistors/54)
[Wire-wound Ceramic resistor 350C](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-passive-product/SBCHE1510KJ/SBCHE1510KJ-ND/2365138)